# Save data into a file: where the adress of the file is given by the user

Tags: c, file-io

I ran a simulation for some data y1, y2,..yn and generate vectors w, mu. At each simulation these results are stored into a file, let us say (normally w and mu are very long vectors 10,000 entries)

```
/home/carlos/Documents/Results/w.txt
/home/carlos/Documents/Results/mu.txt
```

But if I want to run my algorithm with other data set, and do not want to lose the previous results, I have to go directly into my C code and change (or move the w.txt, mu.txt to other file)

```
/home/carlos/Documents/Results/OtherData/w.txt
/home/carlos/Documents/Results/OtherData/mu.txt
```

I do not want to go every time into my C code to change the address(or move again and again w.txt, mu.txt), I would like to just create a new folder with a name: OtherData and store the data there just giving the address

```
/home/carlos/Documents/Results/OtherData/
```

as an input for the code

I did a very simplified example but it does not work, could somebody give me a hand?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(char *dir){
  char dir_happy[100] = *dir, dir_sad[100]=*dir;
  FILE *ffile_happy, *ffile_sad;

  strcat(dir_happy, "/happy.txt");
  strcat(dir_sad, "/sad.txt");

  ffile_happy = fopen("dir_happy.txt", "w");
  ffile_sad = fopen("dir_sad.txt", "w");

  fprintf(ffile_happy, "Hello!, happy world\n");
  fprintf(ffile_sad, "Hello!, sad world\n");

  fclose(ffile_happy);
  fclose(ffile_sad);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the arguments to `main()` wrong. The proper prototype is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Where `argc` is the number of arguments given, and `argv` is a vector holding each argument. The first argument (in `argv[0]`) is generally the program's name.

Answer (score 1):

Untested. Have fun.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH 100
#define DEFAULT_DIR "."
#define HAPPY_NAME "/happy.txt"
#define SAD_NAME "/sad.txt"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char name1[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH+1], name2[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH+1];
    size_t dirlen;
    char *dir = DEFAULT_DIR;
    FILE *ffile_happy, *ffile_sad;

    if (argc == 2) {
        dir = argv[1];
    }
    dirlen = strlen(dir);
    if (len + strlen(HAPPY_NAME) > MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Directory name too long. Program aborted.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (len + strlen(SAD_NAME) > MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Directory name too long. Program aborted.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(name1, dir); strcat(name1, HAPPY_NAME);
    strcpy(name2, dir); strcat(name2, SAD_NAME);

    ffile_happy = fopen(name1, "w");
    if (ffile_happy == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file \"%s\" for writing. Program aborted.\n", name1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ffile_sad = fopen(name2, "w");
    if (ffile_sad == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file \"%s\" for writing. Program aborted.\n", name2);
        fclose(ffile_happy);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* use files */

    fclose(ffile_happy);
    fclose(ffile_sad);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks great! thanks pmg! I'll have to test it but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`void main(char *dir)` is the problem.

Main takes 2 args `int/void main(int argc, char *argv[])`

- **argc** is the number of arguments to the executable.
- **argv[0]** is the filename of the executable.
- **argv[1..n]** are the arguments passed (normally space separated, with quotes allowed)

So /a.out Hello "Look at me" would parse as

- argv[0] => './a.out'
- argv[1] => 'Hello'
- argv[2] => 'Look at me'

Comment: In hosted C, `main` returns a `int`. Any compiler that accepts a `main` returning something else (or `void`) without a diagnostic, is a not a C compiler.

Comment: Then I guess most C compilers aren't C compilers.

Comment: that's right. Many so-called C compilers are not, in fact, out of the box C compilers, but need a great deal of configuration to become a true C compiler.

Comment: If we're talking about correctly implementing a spec in a compiler, then I agree. If we're talking about what works (and is used) in real-world implementations, then it's a trivial detail. It is common to use `exit(int)` to terminate, rather than `return int`, to reduce conditional logic. Or in agile terms, using `int main` instead of `void main` is a feature to implement when needed.